# In c++, how to create a conversion from T to T*?

Tags: c++, templates

In preparing to a OOP exam, I enjoyed seeing g++ compile the following code (without an instantiation) even though it appeared to make no sense:

```
template<class T> void f() {
    T t = "a";
    t += 5.6;
    t->b();
    T* p = t;
    p = p*(t/"string");
}
```

I then set out on a challenge to make this instantiate and compile.

I created the following class:

```
class A {
    public:
    A(const char* s) {}
    void operator+=(double d) {}
    A operator/(char* str) {return A("");}
    A* operator->() {return this;}
    A* operator=(A& a) {return &a;}
    void b() {}
};
A* operator*(A* a, A b) {return new A("");}
```

which allowed almost all of the  template to work, except the line

```
T* p = t;
```

My question is, what operator or constructor will make this line work? Currently it gives me "error: cannot convert ‘A’ to ‘A*’ in initialization"

Comment: Any particular reason for doing this horrible thing, or is it just to see if you can?

Comment: This is to prepare to an exam, and as an exercise.

I promise to never write code that looks like this in anything real :)

Comment: Ugh. You might want to skip an examen that demands you to write such code.

Comment: `t/"string"` will not compile anymore in a C++0x compiler. I recommend you to change the operator to take a `char const*` instead (this conversion dropping constness has been deprecated a long time).

Comment: @Tzafrir, i like the following quiz: Given `template<typename T> void f() { T t = "hello"; T u = &t; }`, what is the shortest way to instantiate a valid `f`?

Comment: class A {
        public:
        A(const char* c) {}
        A(A* t) {}
    };

Works. Is there anything simpler?

Comment: @Tzafrir, yeah there is a simplier way. `T` can be `const void*` :)

Comment: I see, nice. This is getting dirty indeed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a completely meaningless line.

But to make it compilable, you can provide the conversion operator:

```
operator A* () { return 0; }
```

Hope you realize how evil this is.

Answer (score 7):

Use the type conversion operator?

```
class A {
   //...
public:
    template< class T > 
    operator T*() { return this; }
};
```

But clearly, it's bad practice.

Comment: ...but it's really bad practice. You want to know wether you are dealing with an object on the stack or with a pointer to an object wherever.

Comment: Fixed the example to make it work with VS2008, then added that it's bad practice.

Comment: Works as well.

This gives me a lot more conversions than I needed, which is why I didn't mark it as my selected answer.

Answer (score 2):

While Klaim told you how, implicit conversions to pointers of `T` may lead to subtile bugs - so please don't do this in production code.
Explicitly taking the address via the `&` operator avoid these bugs and says more clearly what your intent was.

Also note that your assignment operator looks, lets say unusual. See the [C++ FAQ lite entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-operators.html) for more details.

Comment: I agree. This was as a head-in-the-wall exercise.

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
  // ...
  template <typename T>
  operator T*() const
  {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My C/C++ is pretty rusty but I really want to say that it's just

```
T* p = &t;
```